# How can I fix this up to do generic conversion to Nullable<T>?

Tags: c#, nullable

I currently use this handy conversion extension method to do conversions between types:

```
    public static T To<T>(this IConvertible obj)
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
    }
```

However, it doesn't like converting valid values to Nullable, for example, this fails:

```
    "1".To<int?>();
```

Obviously, 1 is easily converted to an (int?), but it gets the error:

```
    Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.
```

This is an obviously simplified example, in reality I'm using it to do conversions from string types like so:

```
packageDb.Quantity = package.package.ElementDeep(Namespace + "PackageQuantity", Namespace + "ActualQuantity", Namespace + "Quantity").ValueOrNull().To<int?>();
```

If Convert.ChangeType doesn't like Nullable, anyone have any great ideas?

Comment: See my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773078/c-convert-string-to-nullable-type-int-double-etc

Answer (score 104, accepted):

```
public static T To<T>(this IConvertible obj)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);
    Type u = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);

    if (u != null)
    {
        return (obj == null) ? default(T) : (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, u);
    }
    else
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, t);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luke!  This is perfect.  It was t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)) and Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t) that really helped me out here.  This is good stuff.  Thanks again.

Comment: Depending on your needs its helpful to change if (obj == null)
 TO if (obj == null || obj is String && obj.ToString() == "")

Comment: As a slight simplification/clarification, if T is nullable, and obj is null, isn't `return default(T)` always the same as simply `return null` ?

Comment: @goodeye: Yes, it is the same, but the compiler won't allow `return null` unless the method also has a `where T : class` constraint.

Comment: @JarrettWidman I would implement the string use case you mention as a method overload where the parameter is a string instead of an IConvertible.  Let the compiler do some optimization for you.

Comment: This is gold.  I ended up using a parameter of object instead for my purposes, but it works like a charm.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: Just bear in mind your `To<T>` method behaves subtly different when it comes to handling of null input for value type outputs. For instance, `To<int>(null)` explodes unlike `Convert.ToInt32(null)` which will return 0. This can be desirable, but is a slight difference in behaviour nevertheless, keep in mind. Also an input of `IConvertible` is not strictly needed since `Convert.ChangeType` will return the same object if the input and output types are the same, but its still a good constraint to have.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static T To<T>(this IConvertible obj) 
{
    Type t = typeof(T);
    if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
        t = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];

    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, t); 
}
```

But if the conversion fail, it will throw an exception, not returning a null as should be expected.

Comment: good answer, perfectly on track, but I can only award correct to 1, and Luke's does the null checking.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm missing the point, but in the instance of Nullable, how does your method provide either a readability, performance, or maintenance advantage over a simple cast, like `(int?)1` ?

Aside from that, perhaps another extension method?

```
public static T? ToNullable<T>(this T obj) where T:struct
{
    return (T?)obj;
}
```

**Edit**

After reviewing your edit, why would the generic function that I provided not work as a substitute to your `To<T>` function in that line of code? You can't allow a conversion to Nullable for any type (which is why `ChangeType` doesn't work) because that generic only accepts value types. You'll either have to use a function like the one I provided or change your signature of `To<T>` to only accept value types and add a special case for `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: Is there a way to roll this into my existing method, and have it detect the nullable generic, and handle appropriately?

Comment: Well, you could say this... if(typeof(T).IsGeneric && typeof(T).GetGenericTypeDefinition().Name.StartsWith("Nullable")) will tell you if the type is nullable. You can then apply the special case, but I'm not sure that can work when To<T> accepts non-struct types. What would be the issue of just changing to use ToNullable<T> when that's what you want?

Answer (score 3):

I've ended up with this

```
private static T To<T>(this Object @object, Boolean returnDefaultOnException)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    Type underlyingTypeOfNullable = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type);
    try
    {
        return (T) Convert.ChangeType(@object, underlyingTypeOfNullable ?? type);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        if (returnDefaultOnException)
            return default(T);
        String typeName = type.Name;
        if (underlyingTypeOfNullable != null)
            typeName += " of " + underlyingTypeOfNullable.Name;
        throw new InvalidCastException("Object can't be cast to " + typeName, exception);

    }
}
public static T To<T>(this Object @object) { return @object.To<T>(returnDefaultOnException: false); }
public static T ToOrDefault<T>(this Object @object) { return @object.To<T>(returnDefaultOnException: true); }
```

It behaves like the LINQ extension methods `Single` and `SingleOrDefault` and `First` and `FirstOrDefault`.

In short, `To<T>()` tries to convert and throws on failure while `ToOrDefault<T>()` tries to convert and returns `default(T)` on failure.

Answer (score 2):

Luke's solution was good for me (and obviously got his up vote) but I simplified it for me this way

```
    private static Type ResolveType(String typeName)
    {
        Type t = Type.GetType(typeName);
        if (t == null)
            return null;

        Type u = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);

        if (u != null) {
            t = u;
        }
        return t;
    }
```

because I started from a string not from a type...
thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This is the method that I currently use (I got my answer on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773078/c-convert-string-to-nullable-type-int-double-etc)), it converts from string to nullable type:

```
    public static Nullable<T> ConvertToNullable<T>(this string s) where T : struct
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Trim()))
        {
            TypeConverter conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T)));
            return (Nullable<T>)conv.ConvertFrom(s);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

extend @LukeH code:

```
public static T GetValue<T>(string Literal, T DefaultValue)
    {
        if (Literal == null || Literal == "" || Literal == string.Empty) return DefaultValue;
        IConvertible obj = Literal;
        Type t = typeof(T);
        Type u = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);

        if (u != null)
        {
            return (obj == null) ? DefaultValue : (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, u);
        }
        else
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, t);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer.

Comment: if your Literal is null, return DefaultValue. else Convert Literal to T Type.

Answer (score 0):

This method does what you need, and it looks nice while doing it.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// <para>More convenient than using T.TryParse(string, out T). 
    /// Works with primitive types, structs, and enums.
    /// Tries to parse the string to an instance of the type specified.
    /// If the input cannot be parsed, null will be returned.
    /// </para>
    /// <para>
    /// If the value of the caller is null, null will be returned.
    /// So if you have "string s = null;" and then you try "s.ToNullable...",
    /// null will be returned. No null exception will be thrown. 
    /// </para>
    /// <author>Contributed by Taylor Love (Pangamma)</author>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="p_self"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T? ToNullable<T>(this string p_self) where T : struct
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(p_self))
        {
            var converter = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
            if (converter.IsValid(p_self)) return (T)converter.ConvertFromString(p_self);
            if (typeof(T).IsEnum) { T t; if (Enum.TryParse<T>(p_self, out t)) return t;}
        }

        return null;
    }
```

https://github.com/Pangamma/PangammaUtilities-CSharp/tree/master/src/StringExtensions