# How to write a generic conversion method which would support converting to and from nullable types?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, type-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix this up to do generic conversion to Nullable<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793714/how-can-i-fix-this-up-to-do-generic-conversion-to-nullablet)

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
    {
        public static T To<T>(this object value)
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
        } 
    }
```

My above extension method helps converting a type to another type but it doesn't support nullable types.

For example, {0} works fine but {1} doesn't work:

```
{0}:
var var1 = "12";
var var1Int = var1.To<int>();

{1}:
var var2 = "12";
var var2IntNullable = var2.To<int?>();
```

So, how to write a generic conversion method which would support converting to and from nullable types?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried `Nullable<int>`?

Comment: @MrLister, you can't specify a type within the generic method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for me:

```
public static T To<T>(this object value)
{
    Type t = typeof(T);

    // Get the type that was made nullable.
    Type valueType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));

    if (valueType != null)
    {
        // Nullable type.

        if (value == null)
        {
            // you may want to do something different here.
            return default(T);
        }
        else
        {
            // Convert to the value type.
            object result = Convert.ChangeType(value, valueType);

            // Cast the value type to the nullable type.
            return (T)result;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        // Not nullable.
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Comment: good, ta. just one point; it's not just value types which can be nullable e.g. DateTime? (DateTime is a reference type itself as far as I know) so your code comments may need to be corrected ;)

Comment: no - DateTime is a value type, since it is a struct.  Only classes are reference types in .NET

Comment: you're right! should have already checked!

Comment: Some minor nip and tuck would make that method a bit shorter.