# Value of 'String' cannot be converted to Type 'T'. Generic function for getting query strings?

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, query-string, type-conversion

I've got this function:

```
Public Shared Function GetQueryStringValue(Of T As Structure)(ByVal queryStringVariable As String) As T
        Dim queryStringObject As Nullable(Of T) = Nothing
        If queryStringVariable <> Nothing Then
            If HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString(queryStringVariable) IsNot Nothing Then
                queryStringObject = DirectCast(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString(queryStringVariable), T)
            End If
        End If

        Return queryStringObject
End Function
```

Which I was hoping to call like this:

```
Dim userId As Integer = SessionUtil.GetSessionValue(Of Integer)("uid")
```

I was trying to make it generic since in the end a query string value could be at least an integer or a string, but possibly also a double and others. But I get the error:

`Value of 'String' cannot be converted to Type 'T'`

I did this exact same thing with Session variables and it worked. Anyone know a way to make this work?

**EDIT:** Jonathan Allen below has a more simpler answer using CObj() or CTypeDynamic(). But the below also works from [Convert string to nullable type (int, double, etc...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773078/c-convert-string-to-nullable-type-int-double-etc)

```
Dim conv As TypeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(T))
queryStringObject = DirectCast(conv.ConvertFrom(queryStringVariable), T)
```

Comment: I'm curious about the reference to Type 'T' in the error message. Is this a runtime or compile-time error? Please forgive the lack of a definitive answer; I've avoided VB since VB6.

Comment: @Steve Morgan, it was a compile-time error.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The safest way is to use CTypeDynamic. This will ensure that implicit/explicit operators are used.

```
Function Convert(Of T)(s As String) As T
    Return Microsoft.VisualBasic.CTypeDynamic(Of T)(s)
End Function
```

This will work for simple types but will fail for complex ones.

```
Function Convert(Of T)(s As String) As T
    Return CType(CObj(s), T)
End Function
```

Comment: Great this works, I also found out this also works: `Dim conv As TypeConverter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType(T)), then set it via
     queryStringObject = DirectCast(conv.ConvertFrom(queryStringVariable), T)`

Comment: please check out my related but different question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792050/generic-function-with-of-t-as-what-to-accept-string-integer-datetime I ran into a problem when implementing it.

Answer (score 5):

I think the issue is that you can't *cast* a string to an Integer (or indeed, many types). It needs to be parsed instead.

I'm not sure, but CType() might do the job instead of DirectCast().

Comment: Don't think that is the issue as I can type: `DirectCast("5", Integer)` no problem. Same with `CType`. But could you provide an example of what you mean? I am somewhat familiar with parsing, but not generically...

Comment: I also thought it was the same reason as this answer. Maybe VB does some extra magic. Can you put in a breakpoint and see that the value is actually convertable to an Integer? And does DirectCast("5", Integer) actually execute without error in VB?

Comment: The code `DirectCast("5", Integer)` doesn't compile under VB 10.

Comment: Okay I am actually wrong, My error list must have been slow to update, Jonathan Allen is right, that doesn't compile.