# How to set a struct value T from Type

Tags: c#, generics

I'm using the extension from [Joel's string-to-nullable-type answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773078/c-convert-string-to-nullable-type-int-double-etc):

```
public static Nullable<T> ToNullable<T>(this string s) where T: struct
{
    Nullable<T> result = new Nullable<T>();
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && s.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            TypeConverter conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
            result = (T)conv.ConvertFrom(s);
        }
    }
    catch { } 
    return result;
}
```

And in my code, I've got the data from a Type. Is there a way to cast or use that extension using Type?

**UPDATE 1:**

```
var values = from p in xdoc.Descendents("Answers")
         select r.Attribute("Value").Value.ToNullable<Type.GetType(r.DataType)>()
```

r.DaraType is a data string.

Comment: what does your code look like?

Comment: @Daniel I've write the code line

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but instead of testing (!String.IsNullOrEmpty && s.Trim().Length > 0), you can just test (!String.IsNullOrWhitespace()).

Comment: The big question is what do you intend to do with `values` seeing as how you don't know its type at compile time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't specify a generic type argument to be the result of a method call that returns a Type object.

i.e. this is invalid `ToNullable<Type.GetType(r.DataType)>()`

The type needs to be evaluated at compile time and if your syntax was valid the compiler could not tell what the type was in result of your linq query.