# TryParse to a nullable type

Tags: c#, .net, null, nullable, tryparse

I would like to try to parse a `string` as a `DateTime?`, and if it fails then set the value to `null`. The only way I can think to do this is the following, but it doesn't seem very neat.

```
DateTime temp;
DateTime? whatIActuallyWant = null;
if (DateTime.TryParse(txtDate.Text, out temp)) whatIActuallyWant = temp;
```

Is this the only way?

Comment: Consider to use generic conversion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773078/convert-string-to-nullable-type-int-double-etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generic TryParse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961656/generic-tryparse)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

How about this:

```
DateTime? whatIActuallyWant = DateTime.TryParse(txtDate.Text, out temp) ? (DateTime?)temp : null;
```

You get a one-liner out of this (unfortunately need the `DateTime?` cast otherwise won't compile) - but personally I would probably stick to the `null` initialization and the subsequent `if` - it's just easier to read.

Comment: I tried this before, but it returns the error: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DateTime' and '<null>'.

Comment: @James: see the cast to `DateTime?` - unfortunately its necessary because both terms must be implicitly convertible - an alternative is `? temp : (DateTime?)null;`

Comment: @James, let's look at this. You have to declare the `temp` variable still, so add that line. So we've taken 3 lines of your code down to 2. Is this version more or less readable? We have to scroll to see it all. More or less complex? We've introduced a cast. Half a dozen in one hand, 6 in the other, if you ask me.

Comment: I've just thought - how about `DateTime? whatIActuallyWant = null; try { whatIActuallyWant = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDate.Text); } catch { }`

Comment: @James: I would not go that route - if you expect your parsing might fail use `TryParse` - in any case an exception thrown is very costly at run time, I would try to avoid that.

Comment: why doesn't this work with Boolean.Parse...I have to add 2-3 extra lines.

Answer (score 17):

If your going to be performing this operation more than once then I recommend adding a simple extension method for ease of use...

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static DateTime? ToDateTime(this string val)
    {
        DateTime temp;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(val, out temp))
            return temp;
        else 
            return null;
    }
}
```

Which you can then use very easily...

```
DateTime? ret1 = "01/01/2011".ToDateTime();
DateTime? ret2 = myString.ToDateTime();
```