# How to Convert a String to a Nullable Type Which is Determined at Runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, datetime, nullable

I have the below code and I'd need to convert a string to a type which is also specified from String:

```
 Type t = Type.GetType("System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]");

            object d = Convert.ChangeType("2012-02-23 10:00:00", t);
```

I get the below error messagE:

```
Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'.
```

How would that be nicely possible?

I know one ugly way would be to check whether the type is nullable using if:

```
    Type possiblyNullableType = Type.GetType("System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]");

    var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(possiblyNullableType);

    Object result;

    // if it's null, it means it wasn't nullable
    if (underlyingType != null)
    {
        result = Convert.ChangeType("2012-02-23 10:00:00", underlyingType);
    }
```

Would there be any better way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are two problems.

Firstly, `Convert.ChangeType` just plain does not support nullable types.

Secondly, even if it did, by boxing the result (assigning it to an `object`), you'd already be converting it to a `DateTime`.

You could special case nullable types:

```
string s = "2012-02-23 10:00:00";
Type t = Type.GetType("System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]");
object d;

if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        d = null;
    else
        d = Convert.ChangeType(s, t.GetGenericArguments()[0]);
}
else
{
    d = Convert.ChangeType(s, t);
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to check t.IsGenericType? the t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) part would cover that; wouldn't it?

Comment: @William `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` throws an exception if the type isn't generic.

Comment: Thank you so much for this elegant solution, you saved my day!

Answer (score 14):

I wrote the below generic helper method which works in most scenarios (not tested with generic types):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Object result =
        ConvertValue(
            "System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]",
            "2012-02-23 10:00:00");
}

public static Object ConvertValue(string typeInString, string value)
{
    Type originalType = Type.GetType(typeInString);

    var underlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(originalType);

    // if underlyingType has null value, it means the original type wasn't nullable
    object instance = Convert.ChangeType(value, underlyingType ?? originalType);

    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the most elegant and working solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static T GetValue<T>(string Literal, T DefaultValue)
    {
        if (Literal == null || Literal == "" || Literal == string.Empty) return DefaultValue;
        IConvertible obj = Literal;
        Type t = typeof(T);
        Type u = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);

        if (u != null)
        {
            return (obj == null) ? DefaultValue : (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, u);
        }
        else
        {
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, t);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Unless you really need to do it dynamically.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
{
   return new DateTime?();
}
else
{
   return new DateTime?(DateTime.Parse(input));
}
```

---

Possibly you could check to see if your type is one of the 'nullable' types and then maybe you could find something useful here:

[Convert string to nullable type (int, double, etc...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773078/c-sharp-convert-string-to-nullable-type-int-double-etc)

Comment: I can't specify DateTime, it's determined at runtime.

Comment: `return new DateTime?();` should be replaced by `return null;`.

Comment: Perhaps if you could supply some more information about what you're trying to do as opposed to what you're currently doing we could advise?