# convert string null value to int

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to insert NULL value into a column type 'int'. I am using the following function but still I am getting InvalidOperationException.  Here is my code. Please suggest.

p.type_id value is "null".

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type_id", ToNullableInt32(p.type_id))

    public static int ToNullableInt32(string s)
    {
        int i;
        if (Int32.TryParse(s, out i)) return i;
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Your return type should be a nullable int: `int?`.

Comment: Your `ToNullableInt32` method shouldn't even compile so I'm a little confused as to how you're getting to an `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: I tried with int? but still I am getting error message. It works only if I use DBNull.value. cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type_id", DBNull.Value)

Comment: I updated my answer to include a possible solution to that as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to nullable type (int, double, etc...)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773078/convert-string-to-nullable-type-int-double-etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
 public static int? ToNullableInt32(string s)
{
    int i;
    return (Int32.TryParse(s, out i)) ? i : null;
}
```

EDIT: I noticed your comment to your original question about it only working with DBNull values. In that case, try adding...

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type_id", ToNullableInt32(p.type_id) ?? DBNull.Value)
```

...in addition to the ToNullableInt32 method update.

Answer (score 2):

It should be a nullable int

```
public static int? ToNullableInt32(string s) 
{
   ...
}
```