# Azure Blob download as byte array error "Memory Stream is not expandable"

Tags: azure

I want to download blob as byte array, but above mention error occurs.
my code is as follows

```
Dim fullFileBytes() As Byte = {}
Dim objAzureStorage As New AzureCloudStorage

Dim fullImageBlob As Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob = objAzureStorage.CloudContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(row(0))

fullImageBlob.DownloadToByteArray(fullFileBytes, 0)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Blob storage: DownloadToByteArray VS DownloadToStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24312527/azure-blob-storage-downloadtobytearray-vs-downloadtostream)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since I have not worked with VB.Net, let me provide an answer in C#. Essentially what I have done is read the blob's contents in memory stream and then converted that to a byte array and return that array.

```
    private static byte[] ReadBlobInByteArray()
    {
        var cred = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(cred, true);
        var container = account.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference("container-name");
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("blob-name");
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            blob.DownloadToStream(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: that I have done,but when i use like this                     cblobFull.BeginDownloadToByteArray() ,its give error that I have mention above.

Comment: The reason you're getting this error is because byte array's size can't be changed. If you wish to read directly in a byte array, first you have to fetch blob's properties which will give you blob's length. Then you would create a byte array of that size and then read the blob's contents in that byte array. This is not recommended because you're making 2 network calls: one to read blob's properties and two to actually download the blob. In the approach I have mentioned, you only make one network call. HTH.