# Downloading file to browser from Azure Blob Storage using SAS

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

In my `DownloadFile` page's `Page_Load` method, the filename a user wishes to download is retrieved from the query string. The file is hosted in an Azure Blob Storage account. I am attempting to download the file using shared access signatures (SAS) via this approach:

```
var containerName = "containerName";
var con = "connectionString";
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(con);

var blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("file.pdf");
var sasToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
{
    Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10),
}, new SharedAccessBlobHeaders()
{
    ContentDisposition = "attachment; filename=file.pdf"
});

var blobUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}", blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri, sasToken);
Response.Redirect(blobUrl);
```

However, this does not download the file. Instead, the browser just shows a garbled character stream of the file:

[image: Garbled Characters]

The `blobUrl` appears to be valid. But the `Response.Redirect` isn't working as expected. Am I doing something wrong?

**Note**: I am using WebForms (unfortunately), *not* MVC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Downloading Azure Blob files in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6752000/downloading-azure-blob-files-in-mvc3)

Comment: Is setting the ContentType property to `application/pdf` required?

Comment: @Glenn I don't believe so because the url is to the actual file, which is hosted in Azure. The response does not contain the file. I did try that though without any luck.

Comment: @404 unfortunately, no difference. Also, the file itself isn't included in the response. It's not being downloaded to the server first. Intead, a URL is generated using an Azure Storage SAS token, and the `Response.Redirect` is to redirect to that generated URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a workaround by using an `iframe`. If I add an `iframe` to the page:

`<iframe id="iframeFile" runat="server" style="display:none;"></iframe>`

Then set the source in the codefile:

`iframeFile.Src = blobUrl;`

It downloads the file.

This may not be ideal, and I'm still not sure why `Response.Redirect` isn't working as expected. So I'm certainly open to other suggestions as well. But this workaround does resolve the issue of not being able to download the file.