# int.Parse, Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#

How would I parse an empty string? `int.Parse(Textbox1.text)` gives me an error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.
>   System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

If the text is empty (`Textbox1.text = ''`), it throws this error. I understand this error but not sure how to correct this.

Comment: you wouldn't, check if the string is empty before trying to parse it. if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Textbox1.Text)). Obviously this will still give you an error if the string is not a number so add some validation to the input

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you're looking to default to 0 on an empty textbox (and throw an exception on poorly formatted input):

```
int i = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Textbox1.Text) ? 0 : int.Parse(Textbox1.Text);
```

If you're looking to default to 0 with any poorly formatted input:

```
int i;
if (!int.TryParse(Textbox1.Text, out i)) i = 0;
```

Comment: the second code snippet suggests that TryParse will leave the previous value intact when returning false but it will zero it instead. better write `int i; if (!int.TryParse(Textbox1.Text, out i)) i = 0;` or someone thinks the following would work `int i = -1; int.TryParse(Textbox1.Text, out i);`

Comment: `out i` - it will be assigned to `0` if not parsed, so for zero check and assignment are extra.

Comment: Personally, I prefer ```IsNullOrWhitespace``` for this.

Answer (score 17):

Well, what do you *want* the result to be? If you just want to validate input, use [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
int result;

if (int.TryParse(Textbox1.Text, out result)) {
    // Valid input, do something with it.
} else {
    // Not a number, do something else with it.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Textbox1.text))
    var number = int.Parse(Textbox1.text);
```

Or even better:

```
int number;

int.TryParse(Textbox1.Text, out number);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
int number;
if (int.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, out number))
{
    //Some action if input string is correct
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If the input is a number or an empty string this will work. It will return zero if the string is empty or else it will return the actual number.

```
int.Parse("0"+Textbox1.Text)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also use an extension method like this:

```
public static int? ToNullableInt32(this string s)
{
    int i;
    if (Int32.TryParse(s, out i)) return i;
    return null;
}
```

Here's the reference: [How to parse a string into a nullable int in C# (.NET 3.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030/how-to-parse-a-string-into-a-nullable-int-in-c-sharp-net-3-5#)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with `int.TryParse()` erroring with negative numbers.

Here's what I used and it worked:

```
int.TryParse("-1",NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var num);
```

The `NumberStyles` enum can be OR'd together with '|', so you can pick and choose the format combinations. `NumberStyles.Number` covers about any number.

Comment: I'm wondering what culture writes negative numbers differently!

Answer (score -2):

you can wrap it with simple `try/catch`...

Comment: Terrible way to accomplish this. Always validate the input - don't plan for exceptions.

Comment: This is a valid alternative but you should be clear that you only want `catch(System.FormatException)`

Comment: @Umer - what I meant is you don't need to think a lot just wrap the code with it and get on with your life...

Comment: @RobinVanPersi agreed, if you can't find a dirty solution, you can't think a faster solution :)

Comment: @Ryan Don't plan for exceptions?  Can you explain?  Please.

Comment: @johnny: Better worded as "exceptions are for exceptional circumstances" or something. Anyway, the point being this: if you can check your input in a straightforward way before feeding it to stuff, do so. It reads better and helps avoid swallowing exceptions you may not have intended to.