# DropDownList Error Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have two dropdown list and the dropdown list is bind with the database by LINQ. and I am adding dropdownlist value at 0 indexes is a string that firstly appears on screen but If any user wrongly selects this string they got an error that showing in error screenshot so how can bypass this error.
 here is code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(!IsPostBack)
        { 

            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Course"));
            DataClassesDataContext d = new DataClassesDataContext();
            var dd = d.TblCourseMasters.OrderBy(a => a.Name);
            foreach (var item in dd)
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem(item.Name, item.Id.ToString()));
            }
        }

    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList2.Items.Clear();
        DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Label"));
        DataClassesDataContext d = new DataClassesDataContext();
        var dd = d.TblLabelMasters.Where(a => a.Cid == int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));
        foreach (var item in dd)
        {
            DropDownList2.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem(item.LabelName, item.Id.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

I got an error when I select string value `DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Course"));` & `DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Label"));` here is **error screenshot** [image: error screenshot]

and here is **UI screenshot** [image: UI screenshot]

so please suggest me some ideas...?????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [int.Parse, Input string was not in a correct format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372210/int-parse-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format)

Comment: What does the debugger say the value of `SelectedValue` is? Presumably it's not an integer.

Comment: what is the type of `item.Id` that you bind to the list box?

Comment: The error is actually on line 31. That code just doesn't actually execute until line 32. LINQ statements are lazy-evaluated when their results are needed. This question isn't really a duplicate of the linked question, since knowing why requires knowing how LINQ works.

Comment: all id is int type

Comment: `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` is not a string containing an integer but a `ListItem`. You probably want to use `DropDownList1.SelectedValue.Value`. So the full updated line should be: `var dd = d.TblLabelMasters.Where(a => a.Cid == int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the issue came from `int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue)` in line 31 where `DropDownList1.SelectedValue` might not be in a correct format and cannot be parsed.

Why does the error come from line 32 (as indicated in the screenshot) is because line 31 (`var dd = d.TblLabelMasters.Where(a => a.Cid == int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue));`) is not executed until the foreach loop is executed due to deferred execution.

Hope it helps.