# allow null/empty value for public datatype

Tags: c#, parsing, null

Uploading a file via web form and parsing its contents to a list how do I allow null or empty value when parsing for C.MN,C.LN, C.Val these three are public datatypes declared like this

```
Namespace datatypes

       Public class Uploads
  {

        Public long Mn  {get; set;}
        Public int LN     { get;set    }
         Public int Val    {Get;Set}
    }

  List<Uploads> CDU = new List<Uploads>();
                string[] fields;

                string data = read.ReadLine();
                while ((data = read.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (data.Length != 0)
                    {
                        Uploads C = new Uploads();
                        fields = data.Split(',');
                        C.LN = Convert.ToInt32(fields[0]);
                        C.MN = Convert.ToInt64(fields[1]);                           
                        C.Val = Convert.ToInt32(fields[2]);
                        CDU.Add(C);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, you have to use nullable value types, e.g.

```
public class Uploads
{
    public long? Mn { get; set; }
    public int? LN { get; set; }
    public int? Val { get; set; }
}
```

Of course you'll need to work out whether to give them a value or leave them as null, presumably based on whether the string is empty or not.

For example:

```
C.LN = fields[0] == "" ? (int?) null : Convert.ToInt32(fields[0]);
```

Or just:

```
if (fields[0] != "")
{
    C.LN = Convert.ToInt32(fields[0]);
}
```

As an aside, those names are completely unmaintainable. In six months, will you have any idea what they're meant to mean?

Comment: ya thats what I tried and I still get incorrect input string error during runtime

Comment: @LewSim: Well that's presumably because you didn't do the middle bit that I talked about: "Of course you'll need to work out whether to give them a value or leave them as null." Certainly the code you've shown makes no attempt to do that - it just *always* calls `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: Ok yes that's part I missed to keep them null and continue parsing

Answer (score 2):

Use nullable types like so:

```
public class Uploads
{
    public long? Mn { get; set; }
    public int? LN { get; set }
    public int? Val { get; set }
}
```

For information on parsing a string as a nullable value, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030/how-to-parse-a-string-into-a-nullable-int-in-c-sharp-net-3-5).