# Split string and convert to nullable long

Tags: c#

I have the following code which splits a string and then convert the values to long:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(baIds) ? null : baIds.Split(',').Select(e => long.Parse(e)).ToList(),
```

What I want is to convert the values to nullable long instead.
Any help pls?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem, why do you need nullable longs in the first place?

Comment: If I am understanding you right you could instead of returning `null` try returning `default(long?)`

Comment: Possible duplicate (but with int) https://stackoverflow.com/a/45037/5295849

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse a string into a nullable int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030/how-to-parse-a-string-into-a-nullable-int)

Comment: `(e => (long?)long.Parse(e))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TryParse`

```
List<long?> result = null;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(baIds))
{
    long temp;
    result = baIds.Split(',').Select(e => long.TryParse(e, out temp) ? temp : (long?)null).ToList();
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/uHk99J

Comment: I would remove the `long temp;` line and use `out var temp` instead. But I'm still not convinced OP even needs to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need it to be typed as `long?` then just cast in the `Select`

```
Select(e => (long?)long.Parse(e))
```

If you need to use `null` to indicate something that couldn't be parsed as long then

```
Select(e => long.TryParse(e, out long r) ? r : default(long?))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(baIds) ? null : baIds.Split(',').Select(e => (long?)long.Parse(e)).ToList(),
```